# "Given parent is not an ancestor of this virtual file" error when adding Spring library

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I'm implementing some web app that uses numerous libraries (Spring, Log4j, Jackson,...). Until now, everything worked ok, but if I try to add another Spring library (webmvc - I'm implementing REST API that needs `DispatcherServlet` class), I'm getting the following error when deploying on JBoss AS 7.1.1:

```
    2017-11-28 08:31:26,678 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Office.war"
2017-11-28 08:31:27,973 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Office.ear"."Office.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Office.ear"."Office.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "Office.war" of deployment "Office.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given parent is not an ancestor of this virtual file
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:116) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:110) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.processTlds(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

2017-11-28 08:31:28,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Office.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Office.ear\".\"Office.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Office.ear\".\"Office.war\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment \"Office.war\" of deployment \"Office.ear\""}}
2017-11-28 08:31:28,336 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Office.war in 113ms
2017-11-28 08:31:28,339 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Office.ear in 116ms
2017-11-28 08:31:28,341 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Office.ear"."Office.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Office.ear"."Office.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "Office.war" of deployment "Office.ear"

2017-11-28 08:31:28,347 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Office.ear\".\"Office.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Office.ear\".\"Office.war\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment \"Office.war\" of deployment \"Office.ear\""}}}}
```

Here's my EAR deployment assembly

[image]

and my web module assembly.

[image]

I have no idea why that error appears, other libraries cause no trouble. Any suggestions?

EDIT 1:

I noticed another strange thing. In Eclipse "Add and remove" dialog, there are three entries of Spring webmvc jars at available resources section.

[image]

Where do those entries come from? Could it be Eclipse issue?

EDIT 2:

I've moved all jars directly into `lib` folder (instead of subfolders like `lib/spring/spring-webmvc-4.0.6.jar`) and I deployed my app successfully. Can anyone explain why that error disappeared after moving jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put all jars directly into `lib` folder (and NOT into subfolders like `lib/spring/spring-webmvc.4.0.6.jar`) and I succeeded with deployment. Not sure why - It would be great if someone can explain what is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the previous deployment from standalone/deployments folder. Clean the server and redeploy the EAR. You might try by changing java version to Java 7, if you are using Java 6.

Jboss AS 7.1.1 has lots of such issues. If possible, change the server to Jboss AS 7.2. This is one of the issues that was fixed in JBoss 7.1.2. You can have a look at this [link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3142) about this bug and the release it was fixed in.

Comment: Did that many times, no luck so far. Thanks for suggestion though. I've added another observation to my original question, please take a look.

Comment: I am not able to see the image at my office. I have updated the answer, have a look. Maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading server is not an option at the moment. I've seen that link about JBoss 7.1.1 bug, but I was sure that there is a way to deploy it on JBoss 7.1.1 since I have another app deployed on that server and it uses similar libraries. After comparing both app configurations I tried to put all jars directly into `lib` folder (and NOT in subfolders like `lib/spring/spring-webmvc.4.0.6.jar`) and I succeeded with deployment. Not sure why though...